# Stencil: Mock a Method Call / specific function

Tags: typescript, jestjs, stenciljs

Should be the latest stencil version Date 15.02.:

When running a spec-test, the test can't be run because it fails at:

```
MockHTMLElement is missing assignedElements() method
```

The spec-test is currently written as follows:

```
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { mySelect } from '../my-select';

describe('my-select', () => {
  it('renders', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [mySelect],
      html: `<my-select></my-select>`,
    });
    expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(`
      <my-select>
        <mock:shadow-root>
          <select class='my-select'></select>
        </mock:shadow-root>
      </my-select>
    `);
  });
});
```

my-select contains several parts, the control itself is working "in real", but the test can't be performed because of:

```
componentDidLoad() {
    const slotElement = this.host.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot') as HTMLSlotElement
    this.select = this.host.shadowRoot.querySelector('select') as HTMLSelectElement;

    let options = slotElement.assignedElements() as Element[];

    options.forEach(opt => this.select.appendChild(opt));

    this.select.removeChild(slotElement);

    this.select.value = this.value;
    this.initialized = true;
}
```

After debugging, the reason because the test fails is because the slotElement is created as **MockHTMLElement** (by stencil), which does not provide the **.assignedElements()** method.

So, what can be done here? In java i'd simply mock "HTMLSlotElement" and create a spy on the assignedElements-Method in order to perform further test.

I have absolutly no idea on how to achieve this in a stencil typescript test.